# GTK3+ C FileChooser FileFilter drop-down list does not show on click - why?

Tags: c, gtk3

I am making a GTK3+ GUI program in C (compiled on linux with gcc). I created a file chooser dialog with a file filter containing multiple entries. Everything 'works' as expected (only the filtered file types show up in the file viewer) BUT when I click the drop down file filter button it does not show a drop-down list of the filter entries (file types) - all it does is highlight itself (the button) and nothing else. Otherwise the file chooser works just fine. Googling and looking at the official docs and examples shows I am using the correct APIs as far as I can tell. What am I doing wrong?
Here are the relevant code snippets (the whole code is 6890 lines long), other variables are defined higher up:

```
GtkFileChooser *ffimg_load_chooser;
GtkFileFilter  *ffimg_load_filter;
GtkWidget      *load_file_dialog;
gint res;
GtkFileChooserAction fca_open = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;

 // Set up a file chooser dialog for loading files
 load_file_dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",
                                      GTK_WINDOW(win_main),
                                      fca_open,
                                      "_Cancel",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                      "_Open",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                      NULL);

 // Set up the file selection filter 
 ffimg_load_filter  = gtk_file_filter_new();
 gtk_file_filter_set_name (ffimg_load_filter,"Flat Field Images");
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_load_filter, "*.pgm");                                     
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_load_filter, "*.ppm");                                     
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_load_filter, "*.bmp");                                     
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_load_filter, "*.dou");                                     

 // Set up the 'file load' dialogue with the flat field image choosing
 // settings:
 ffimg_load_chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (load_file_dialog);
 gtk_file_chooser_add_filter (ffimg_load_chooser,ffimg_load_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder (ffimg_load_chooser,FFFile);
 gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW(load_file_dialog),"Flat Field Image");
 
 // Run the 'file load' dialogue
 res = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (load_file_dialog));
 if (res == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {
    char msgtxt[256];
    gchar *filename;
    int imfmt,lht,lwd;
    int16_t bitcount;
    
    filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (ffimg_load_chooser);
     
    // Code to load file, etc.
    g_free(filename);
 }

 gtk_file_chooser_remove_filter(ffimg_load_chooser,ffimg_load_filter);
 gtk_widget_hide(load_file_dialog);
```

The thing looks like this when run:

[image: No drop down file list]

Edit: Thanks to the answer by Sylvester Kruin it now works just fine. I include the modified code below so others can see where I went wrong and how to make it right.

```
static void btn_cs_load_flatfield_click(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) 
// This just gets the file name and checks the format - it doesn't load the image
{
 gint res;
 GtkFileChooserAction fca_open = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN;
 GtkFileChooser *ffimg_load_chooser;
 GtkFileFilter  *ffimg_pgm_filter;
 GtkFileFilter  *ffimg_ppm_filter;
 GtkFileFilter  *ffimg_bmp_filter;
 GtkFileFilter  *ffimg_dou_filter;
 
 ff_pending=0;
 
 // Set up the 'file load' dialogue with the flat field image choosing
 // settings:
 // Set up the flat field correction reference image file selection
 // filter to be used with the file chooser dialog - we only show this
 // when the user clicks the [Select] button in the camera settings
 // window. 
 ffimg_pgm_filter  = gtk_file_filter_new();
 gtk_file_filter_set_name (ffimg_pgm_filter,"pgm images");
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_pgm_filter, "*.pgm");
                                     
 ffimg_ppm_filter  = gtk_file_filter_new();
 gtk_file_filter_set_name (ffimg_ppm_filter,"ppm images");
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_ppm_filter, "*.ppm");
                                     
 ffimg_bmp_filter  = gtk_file_filter_new();
 gtk_file_filter_set_name (ffimg_bmp_filter,"bmp images");
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_bmp_filter, "*.bmp");
                                     
 ffimg_dou_filter  = gtk_file_filter_new();
 gtk_file_filter_set_name (ffimg_dou_filter,"dou images");
 gtk_file_filter_add_pattern (ffimg_dou_filter, "*.dou");                                     

 load_file_dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Load a Flat Field Image",
                                      GTK_WINDOW(Win_main),
                                      fca_open,
                                      "_Cancel",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                                      "_Open",
                                      GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                      NULL);

 ffimg_load_chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (load_file_dialog);

 gtk_file_chooser_add_filter (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (ffimg_load_chooser),ffimg_pgm_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_add_filter (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (ffimg_load_chooser),ffimg_ppm_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_add_filter (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (ffimg_load_chooser),ffimg_bmp_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_add_filter (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (ffimg_load_chooser),ffimg_dou_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_set_filter (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (ffimg_load_chooser),ffimg_pgm_filter);
 // gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder (ffimg_load_chooser,FFFile);
 
 // Run the 'file load' dialogue
 res = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (ffimg_load_chooser));
 if (res == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {
   gchar *filename;
   filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (ffimg_load_chooser);
   test_selected_ff_filename((char *)filename);
   g_free(filename);
  }

 // Remove the filter from the file load dialogue and close it
 gtk_file_chooser_remove_filter(ffimg_load_chooser,ffimg_pgm_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_remove_filter(ffimg_load_chooser,ffimg_ppm_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_remove_filter(ffimg_load_chooser,ffimg_bmp_filter);
 gtk_file_chooser_remove_filter(ffimg_load_chooser,ffimg_dou_filter);
 gtk_widget_destroy(load_file_dialog);
 
 return;
}
```

And it now does a drop down list as expected like so:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop-down list *is* actually shown, the issue is that it only has one item, so it *looks* like the button is just being highlighted.

#### Problem

In your code, you only create one `GtkFileFilter`, and then add all the patterns to it. This means that this *one* filter includes all the different patterns you have there (`*.pgm`, `*.ppm`, etc.), and thus you only have one filter in the list.

#### Solution

If you want one filter for each pattern, you'll need to create and add multiple `GtkFileFilter`s, each with its own pattern. If you want to show *all* of the file types, you might want to create an "All" filter and add all the patterns to it.

Comment: Thanks for this timely answer - I was just revising the code. It works as you explained and I edited my post to show the working code in case others have the same problem. Perhaps you can comment if you think I am doing the 'right' thing by removing all the filters at the end before destroying the widget - or is that not necessary? [PS I noticed in some open source projects that people ignore this way of making a drop-down filter list and create and add a custom combo box for the purpose - so maybe others have had the same problem and just made their own workaround without this knowledge].

Comment: Glad I could help! I don't _think_ removing all the filters is necessary.